# Error in active record when query result from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If we do on console:

```
> Product.all == Product.all.to_a
true
```

But if we do:

```
> Product.all.to_a.where(name: "something")
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x000055b42c6a3f20>>
```

That's not a problem if we won't run this method 'to_a'.

The point is that on this [heroku cache article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-a-rails-3-application-with-memcache) they show this method bellow to use caching:

```
def self.all_cached
  Rails.cache.fetch('Contact.all') { all.to_a }
end
```

And the query result that returned from this method cannot use active_record because it gets the same error that I explained before.

My main goal is to use caching and to know if it is possible to overcome this issue with active_record acknowledge as workable query when it is arrayed.

Comment: Try Product.where(name: "something").to_a

Comment: I didn't understand your suggestion. Can you explain with more details?

Comment: Why do you want to cache it?

Comment: @dan-klasson my database is not 'product' and it can grows to thousands...

Comment: yeah i don't think that's relevant

Comment: @dan-klasson this is just for performance

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem to use activerecord on cached query result with this change:

from:

```
def self.all_cached
  Rails.cache.fetch('Contact.all') { all.to_a }
end
```

to:

```
   def self.all_cached
      Rails.cache.fetch("all_contacts") do
        Contact.all
      end
    end
```

Now it is not arrayed variable.

This issue is only partially solved once the [heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-a-rails-3-application-with-memcache) told that the best approach is to convert to array:

> Note that we cache all.to_a instead of all. This is because since
>   Rails 4 Model.all is executed lazily and you need to convert
>   Contact.all into an array with to_a in order to cache the actual
>   contacts.

Comment: I am the author of this Heroku article. The reason you need `to_a` is to actually execute the query and cache the result of the query. Rails executes the queries lazily and if you omit `to_a` you are actually caching the query and not the result. That might seem to work but it does not do what you want.

If you want a `where` clause you need to add that to your query and then use `to_a` at the end to execute the query and convert the result into an array, just as @Imran suggested in the comment above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So we must convert to array to get the full benefits...I'll try it out. Regards

Comment: I just want to ask you something: if we don't transform to array then do not improve performance in any level or you are just not getting the best?

Comment: Fillype, if you mention @SaschaTrifunovic, he probably will answer to your last comment

Comment: @FillypeFarias you won't get any benefit. I am assuming that performing the query is slow so you want to cache the result of it. If you want a where clause instead of all products just replace `Product.all.to_a` with `Product.where(name: "something").to_a` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you @SaschaTrifunovic you helped a lot :)